# Logout with session_destroy() doesn't work

Tags: php, session, logout

I'm working on a login/logout script. I can't understand why the logout doesn't work: I have tried every possible way, but it just doesn't destroy the session.

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'logout') {
    $_SESSION = array(); 
    session_destroy();

    header("location: /index.php");
    exit();
}
```

I don't have to add `session_start()` beacause the code is in the homepage, and the session is yet started.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT

It actually works when I click on the logout button, in fact i get on the home page and I'm no more logged in. But if I go on another website, and then I go back on mine, I'm logged.

AND, even more strange: With Internet Explorer, it works. How is this possible? I mean, I was used to differences between browser with CSS, not with PHP :)

Comment: You *do* need a session_start() on this page for this to work.

Comment: This is a common question, asked often. Please use the search first. E.g. didn't [logging out a user completely from a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383115/logging-out-a-user-completely-from-a-website) or [PHP ending sessions(different ways) i dont understand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855550/php-ending-sessionsdifferent-ways-i-dont-understand) or [How to destroy the php session with one button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113223/how-to-destroy-the-php-session-with-one-button) shed some light already?

Comment: I know it's a FAQ, but still I didn't find an answer, even looking at all the topics on this site.

Comment: @John Conde: Yes, i meant that session_start() is already on the top of the page

Answer (score 2):

On the top of the page

```
session_start();
```

Other wise the following will not work

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'logout') {
  $_SESSION = array(); 
  session_destroy();
  header("location: /index.php");
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add 
`session_start();` at the top of the page and then try with:

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] === 'logout') {
  $_SESSION = array(); 
  session_destroy();
  header("location:index.php");
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all cookies or only those which are used for login authentication.

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#73484

Comment: There is no need that [you duplicate that code-chunk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16383184/367456) that often here on the website. If you think that answer answers more than one question, leave a comment and link to your previous answer.

Comment: It doesn't work. Already tried destroyng cookies. I don't know what else i could try :)